# Nvidia GeForce 750M Getting really hot on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, games

I already tryed lots of "solutions", none worked, i already tryed to install a new version on nvidia, right now i'm using 331. Even when i'm doing nothing that should make my pc hot it still does. When it was windows i played games on high resolution and my nvidia gpu core didnt got that hot.. Sorry bad english

Comment: What do you consider to be hot? Lately a lot of posts appear about alledged heat problems. When asked for numbers quite normal temperatures are reported. A temperature around 50 degrees Celsius is actually not too hot.

Comment: It already reached at almost 90C

Comment: also, are you sure windows isn't reporting degrees Fahrenheit instead of Celsius or vice versa?

Comment: I'm sure that it's Celsius

Answer (score 0):

According to the Geforce forums:
https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/351453/geforce-basics/gpu-temperature-what-is-good-/post/2529566/#2529566 it is not extremely hot.

Nevertheless there might be something wrong with a fan. If you're worried you can probably have your computer checked in a computershop.

You might try software called tlp to reduce overheating. It apperas to do a good job with the default settings.
To install it do the following:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw

sudo tlp start`

Comment: There's no problem in my pc, because when it has windows it worked really fine. One thing that i notice is that my fan isnt making any noise..

Comment: Then you might have a technical issue. Ubuntu does not stop your fan. Don't you have an indication about rpm of the fan?

Comment: I didnt had any problem with that on windows, right now i'm looking for ways to see my fan speed or to control it

Comment: Well, I just made an edit to my answer. I use this software too and it does a good job.

Comment: It is likely a driver problem. What model laptop is it? I went through a lot of hell trying to get an older NVDIA GPU to work correctly. I had to try an earlier driver to get it to run decently.

Answer (score 0):

if your fan is not coming on, make sure all your sensors are recognized:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acpi lm-sensors
sudo sensors
```

follow the prompts to detect sensors